# How do I reset a rewrite?

Tags: htaccess, rewrite-rules

I made a mistake in writing a previous rewrite in .htaccess. How do I reset it? 
My home_url = http://basicsourcemassage.ca/bsmassage 
My site_url = domain name 
All pages work fine except for the home page/domain url that returns 
 
http://basicsourcemassage.ca/bsm.basicsourcemassage.ca

Comment: Just, like, undo whatever you did you make the rewrite in the first place? Your question is a bit vague. It's hard to provide an answer to something with so little information to work with. Please improve your question.

Comment: Thanks for the heads-up, will provide more info next time. It was my browser cache.

Answer (score 1):

`.htaccess` rules are interpreted and applied on every request, they don't linger on server level and changes apply immediately.

However if you had had 301 redirect set up then it can be cached by browser *very* aggressively. I do not observe redirect you are describing, so that is likely the case.

Note that your home URL 404s for me right now, so you might have more issues than just rewrite there going on.

Comment: Doh! Thanks for the cached by the browser comment. It's my Chrome cache, cause it works fine in Fox and IE. Been so distracted out by it I neglected to do the obvious first. Ya me too with the 404, was gonna look at that next.